# heroku run rails db:seed failed - Rails 7 + fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, production-environment

I have successfully deployed my [Rails app](https://awesome-quote-editor.herokuapp.com/) with Heroku, `heroku run rails db:migrate`, although `heroku run rails db:seed` failed.

Here is the error message

```
➜  quote-editor git:(master) heroku run rails db:seed
Running rails db:seed on ⬢ awesome-quote-editor... up, run.6832 (Free)

== Seeding the database with fixtures ==
WARNING: Rails was not able to disable referential integrity.

This is most likely caused due to missing permissions.
Rails needs superuser privileges to disable referential integrity.

    cause: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_783704777" is a system trigger


rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "line_item_dates" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_048689f618"
DETAIL:  Key (quote_id)=(309456473) is not present in table "quotes".
```

My setup

- Ubuntu 20.04.2
- Ruby 3.1.2
- Rails 7.0.4
- pg 1.4.3 with native extensions

I have both tried to give superuser privileges
`ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;`
and
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE quote_editor_production TO myuser;`

List of databases

```
              Name               |   Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |    Access 
-----------------------------    | --------  | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------------
 quote_editor_development        | paulinetw | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
-----------------------------    | --------  | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------------
 quote_editor_production         | paulinetw | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/paulinetw        
 quote_editor_test               | paulinetw | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *default
  database: quote_editor_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: quote_editor_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: quote_editor_production
  username: quote_editor
  password: <%= ENV["QUOTE_EDITOR_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

I have tried a lot of suggestions but still can't find a way out. I will really appreciate if somebody could help.

Comment: Is there this `309456473` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No i can not find anywhere.  i have been having issues at first to seed in development due PG::ForeignKeyViolation for bin/rails db:fixtures:load but fixed it with 
config.active_record.verify_foreign_keys_for_fixtures = false in application.rb

Comment: in the console, quote_id: 309456473 is present:

irb(main):002:0> Quote.first
  Quote Load (5.9ms)  SELECT "quotes".* FROM "quotes" ORDER BY "quotes"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=>
#<Quote:0x00007f15263f0d80
 id: 309456473,
 name: "First quote",
 created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2022 09:11:26.159630000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2022 09:11:26.159630000 UTC +00:00,
 company_id: 437724769>

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "line_item_dates" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_048689f618" DETAIL:  Key (quote_id)=(309456473) is not present in table "quotes".`

Your seed file is trying to use a `Quote` with ID 309456473, but that quote doesn't exist.

#### UPDATE:

Here are my assumptions:

- In producution, you run `heroku run rails db:migrate`, which works
- In production, you run `heroku run rails db:seed`, which fails.
- In your seed file you have some command that relies upon some code similar to `Quote.find(309456473)` and this fails in production
- In your seed file, when you create `Quotes`, you **are manually setting each quote's ID** as you create it.

Setting the ID of your records on creation is not a good idea. Let the Db generate keys.

In your seed file, wherever you are looking up records by ID, find a different method to locate the record you want by some other attribute.

Don't assume that Heroku Postgres respects or preserves your record IDs from the seed file.

Comment: I have seen this in the error message, as mentioned in my above comment in dev i had db:seeb and (quote_id)=(309456473) exist.
I just failing in production and i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you post your seed file?